# remap template parameters struct

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I'm new with templates and was wondering how I could do the following:
I have a Fixed point structure that allows for fixed point calculations and is defined as follows:

```
template<int bits, int offset>
struct Fixed {
      int64_t raw;
      inline Fixed() {}
      ...
}
```

I'd like to expand this so that I can declare a self defined floating point representation and the compiler translates this to the correct fixed point definition. I tried this as follows:

```
template<int totBits, int expBits, int expOffset>
struct Fixed<exp2(expBits)+totBits-expBits-2,expOffset-totBits+expBits> {
       inline Fixed() {}
       inline explicit Fixed(double value) {
               Quantization function of floating point here
       }
};
```

However, this gives me the error:
"Template argument involves template parameter(s)".

How can I remap the initial template such that I can do the following: `fixed::Fixed<8,3,0> foo;`
And the compiler sees this as: `fixed::Fixed<11,-3> foo;`?

I know that when I assign a value to `foo` I will have to manually quantise it as if it is stored as a floating point: e.g. `foo = fixed::Fixed<8,3,0>(243)` which will give foo = 240 and `foo = fixed::Fixed<8,3,0>(244)` will give foo = 248.

Comment: Can you try: `struct Fixed : public Fixed<calculation>` instead of `struct Fixed<calculation>`

Comment: @JVApen This gives a complaint that I redeclare the template with 3 parameters instead of the original declaration with only 2 parameters.

Comment: @JVApen He'd need to declare the main template with 3 parameters, and make `Fixed<bits, offset>` a partial specialisation for that to work, I believe.

Comment: @StevenLauwereins See @JustinTime you indeed need partial specialization. So should be `struct Fixed<params> : public Fixed<calculation>`

Comment: Also, wouldn't `Fixed<8,3,0>` be equivalent to `Fixed<11,-5>`?  `0-8+3` is `-5`, after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to make `Fixed<bits, offset>` a specialisation of `Fixed<totBits, expBits, expOffset>`, using an invalid value as `expOffset`.

```
// Forward definition.  Third parameter defaults to an invalid value for expOffset.
// Replace default if necessary.
template<int, int, int = 256>
struct Fixed;

// "Main" specialisation.  Used when third parameter is an invalid expOffset.
// Specialises for when third parameter is default.
template<int bits, int offset>
struct Fixed<bits, offset, 256> {
    int64_t raw;
    inline Fixed() {}

    // Dummy implementation for example.
    inline Fixed(int64_t value) : raw(24) {
        std::cout << "Fixed<" << bits << ", " << offset << ">(" << value << ")\n";
    }
};

// Non-specialised implementation, used for any other value of expOffset.
// Inherits from main specialisation.
template<int totBits, int expBits, int expOffset>
struct Fixed : Fixed<static_cast<int>(exp2(expBits))+totBits-expBits-2,expOffset-totBits+expBits> {
    using MyBase = Fixed<static_cast<int>(exp2(expBits))+totBits-expBits-2,expOffset-totBits+expBits>;

    // Dummy implementation for example.
    inline explicit Fixed(double value) : MyBase(42) {
        std::cout << "Fixed<" << totBits << ", " << expBits << ", " << expOffset << ">(" << value << ")\n";
    }
};
```

This allows instantiations of the second variation to inherit from the appropriate instantiation of the first variation, while using the same name.

```
int main() {
    std::cout << "f1:\n";
    Fixed<11, -3> f1(1);
    std::cout << "\nf2:\n";
    Fixed<8,3,0>  f2(1.0);
}
```

[Output](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/905bf5a1e245435d):

```
f1:
Fixed<11, -3>(1)

f2:
Fixed<11, -5>(42)
Fixed<8, 3, 0>(1)
```

Note that this is effectively normal inheritance, albeit with both the base and derived classes being specialisations of the same template; as such, making the second version a separate class may communicate your intent more clearly.

Comment: I followed up on your tip to make it a second class and give the second class a toFixed() function that automatically returns the correctly sized Fixed type. Thanks!

Comment: @StevenLauwereins You're welcome.  Giving them the same name implies that the third value is an optional configuration value, and that, for example, `Fixed<8, 3, 0>` is just a `Fixed` where `bits` is `8` and `offset` is `3`, but that doesn't use the default behaviour for the third parameter; this could confuse anyone that doesn't look at its implementation, hence the suggestion.  There are cases where something like this can be both useful and clear, though, I believe.